# my statements returns empty row, eventho there records with values

Tags: mysql, sql, foreach

i have this function:

```
function get_comments($file_id){

    echo $file_id.'<br /><br />';
    include 'mysql_connect.php'; ($connection is the dblink variable)

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM gastenboek");
    print $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo '<br /><br />';

    foreach($result as $item){
        echo $item['comment'];
    }

}
```

Ive made 2 records in mij db with values for testing (also in comment). print $row_cnt gives me 2 rows but the foreach statement returns nothing? as if im getting empty rows back from the statement?

thnx for the help

Comment: ps: ive used echo $result; and its also empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query is executed but results are not fetched.
Update your code to this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM gastenboek");
print $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo '<br /><br />';

while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $item['comment'];
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the help, this works. why does the results need to be feched? issent $result already filled with all the data from select * ?

Comment: `mysqli_query` will only query the database and return result object. To access rows, we need to fetch them.

Answer (score 0):

You are not fetching the result, see code below:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM gastenboek");
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

 foreach($row as $item){
        echo $item['comment'];
    }
```

Comment: This does not work for some reason mate. This returns 11Sa0a2 instead of the comment. any idea what this returns instead? Think it has something to do with the fetching.